# EC2 creates new instance when I terminate previous

Tags: amazon-ec2

I can't seem to find the configuration setting but when I terminate a free tier instance a new one is created a few minutes later. I want to terminate it permanently and not have it restart. I created the instance using the eclipse tools originally if this makes any difference. I have tried stop and terminate and both will create a new instance and leave my other instances in the "terminated" or "stopped" state. Is there a setting that I can configure to leave it turned off?

Comment: Is any autoscalling involved? Your issue sounds like a typical case  of aws autoscalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out it is the application is configured in elasticbeanstalk. I had to delete the application in ebs and it terminated the application.